# How can I get Courier 10 Pitch font for Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, fonts, inkscape

I created some SVG drawings using Inkscape on my Ubuntu. I now want to edit the SVGs using Inkscape running on Windows 7.

The problem: the drawings has text formatted with `Courier 10 Pitch` font which is missing from my Windows system. Hence, the text is formatted using another font, which messes everything up.

How can I get this font for Windows?

Or perhaps I can make Inkscape embed the font in the SVG from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

You can Download the Courier 10 Pitch Font from [here](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/courier-10-pitch/), a free version [here](http://www.ufonts.com/fonts/courier-10-pitch-bt.html).

You can also manually extract out the font from your Ubuntu Installation and then Install it on Windows. Here's the [Official Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts). To find out where the font exists, see the section: *Manually* under *Installing New Fonts*. There you'll find the common locations in an Ubuntu Installation where the fonts are usually saved.

Comment: I could'nt find the fot in any of the locations listed in /etc/fonts/fonts.conf (at least not by its name).

Comment: also, if this font comes with ubuntu, isn't is supposed to be free?

Comment: > isn't is supposed to be free? -- Not necessarily. A "font" is considered a copyrighted work, like any other. Even if a font is in the public domain, it doesn't mean that the person that reproduces it has to license it for free usage. As for the Ubuntu version, you'll need to find the exact license and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to substitute `Courier New` for `Courier` in Inkscape.

There is an [extension for font replacement](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape-replace-font/downloads/list)

[Complete Guide to Pre-Installed Fonts in Linux, Mac, and Windows](http://www.apaddedcell.com/web-fonts)

[image: Courier equivalents]

Comment: I don't think they look quite the same

Comment: @DavidB: True, if you want an exact match you'll have to check the licences (should all be Free as you say) and copy the font as explained by Abhishek Biswal